# How can I submit a missing document to schengen visa application which I submitted today

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I submitted the schengen visa application from India today. I missed to attached an invitation letter from Germany business.
I want to submit that missing document in the application that I submitted today at VFS mumbai.
Is there a way to add this letter to my application?

Answer (score 1):

You could submit the missing document to VFS, with a covering letter. They will forward it to the consulate. You don't need an appointment with VFS to do that.